# Comparing two arrays of objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, difference

I have two arrays of objects with different sizes.
First one with old data, second one with updated data from server (included old data with new), data can be mixed. I want to get difference between these arrays.

#### My class

```
class Station {
  var dateOfIssue: Date
  var region: String
  var locality: String
  var bsName: String
  var freqIn: String
  var freqOut: String
  var networkType: String
  var provider: String
  var bsUsableName: String
  ...
}
```

#### Arrays I want to compare (example)

```
var a = [Station]()
var b = [Station]()
for _ in 0...5 {      
  a.append(Station(someRandomStationValue...)
}
b = a
for _ in 0...7{
  b.append(Station(someRandomStationValue...)  //array "b" will contain all that array "a" contains and some new values
}
```

How to compare these arrays comparing all fields between and get a new array with differences (like in java: `b.removeAll(a)`)?

Comment: Firstly, you need to use `var` instead of `let` for initialising your arrays in order to append to it. Secondly, one easy way to get the difference between 2 collections is to use `Set`. There is a `subtract` function for that. You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1779475-subtract

Comment: Oh, about let, it's not a "real" code, wrote it for example, mechanical mistake. About Set thanks, will try

Comment: tried use Set, it says me "Cannot convert value of type '[Station]' to specified type 'Set'"

Comment: maybe you can use `Set`.

Comment: Do you have any unique property in Station class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `Set` which provides in-built `.subtract()` and `.subtracting()` methods which removes the common entries inside both the *Sets*

```
struct Station: Hashable,CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Int
    var region: String
    var locality: String
    var bsName: String

    // Just to provide a pretty print statement
    var description: String {
        return "ID: \(id) | region: \(region) | locality: \(locality) | bsName: \(bsName)"
    }
}

var stations1 = Set<Station>()
var stations2 = Set<Station>()

for currentNumber in 0...3 {
    stations1.insert(Station(id: currentNumber, region: "abc", locality: "abc", bsName: "abc"))
}

for currentNumber in 0...5 {
    stations2.insert(Station(id: currentNumber, region: "abc", locality: "abc", bsName: "abc"))
}

// Caluculating the difference here
print(stations2.subtracting(stations1))
```

Comment: Using a Set loses the original order

Comment: Yeah, but if all you want to know is what changes there are between the two, how does the order matter? Plus there is no need for writing your custom logic for eliminating the similar items from the two

Comment: Plus the model has a `dateOfIssue` with which you can later sort the final output

Comment: How does your answer differ from @paivaalan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912920/3687801)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments by koropok you may use `subtract` method:

```
// Added to make original code functional 
// Station must conform to Hashable protocol in order to be stored in the Set
struct Station: Hashable {
    let id: Int
}

var a = [Station]()
for i in 0...5 {
    a.append(Station(id:i))
}

var b = [Station]()
for i in 0...7{
    //array "b" will contain all that array "a" contains and some new values
    b.append(Station(id:i))  
}

var c = Set(b)

// c will contain 6 and 7
c.subtract(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @koropok, a good solution is using `Set`. The first step is to conform your type to `Hashable`. For classes, you'd have to implement `==` and `hash(into:)` functions, but if you use struct you don't have to do anything else other than declaring the conformance. So:

```
struct Station: Hashable {
  var dateOfIssue: Date
  var region: String
  ...
}
```

Now you should be able to add `Station` into a `Set`. Thus:

```
var a = Set<Station>()
for _ in 0...5 {
  a.insert(Station(...))
}
var b = Set<Station>()
a.forEach { b.insert($0) }
for _ in 0...7 {
  b.insert(Station(...))
}

let c = b.subtracting(a)
```

`Set` also provides a handy initializer that you can use to turn your `Station` array into a set:

```
let s = Set(arrayLiteral: [your, station, objects])
```